# Spring Application Events route in Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am having a problem with configuring Spring Application Events with Apache Camel Route. The thing I am to build is a Camel route that listens on a certain directory for files and passes the results as my default Spring Application events, injecting them into ApplicationContext. The only thing I've found on the internet about this particular kind of set-up is from Camel's reference and it's very, euphemistically, concise: http://camel.apache.org/spring-event.html
So I wrote my custom class that extends Spring's `Application Event`. Then I wrote an event handler and configured my route as follows:

@Autowired
private CamelContext ctx;

...

```
  @Bean
public RouteBuilder myRoute() throws Exception {
    RouteBuilder route = new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            String myDirectoryPath = "file://my directory";

            from(myDirectoryPath)
                    .delay(1100)
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .to("spring-event://MySpringEvent");
        }
    };

    ctx.addRoutes(route);
    return route;
}
```

The problem is that this particular setup does not post any Spring events.
The setup works if I, for instance, replace the ending route with rest url that is mapped by controller. Also It works if the last route is just another directory path. So, the question is: how do I configure it properly to handle Spring Events?

Comment: Do you know if this route got published?

Comment: I have no idea. Is it possible that, even if in docs, this route haven't got published?

Comment: can you check if the logs to see if this route has started? In the log you can search for "routes started"

Comment: Yes, it's starting normally in logs. But when I actually try to test it (namely to put a text file in the directory) nothing happens. When I launch, for instance file ->rest route it calls http address normally but when I do file -> spring event, nothing happens. I must be doing something wrong, but nobody has written anything about it on the Internet...